# PHP Mysql CHECK row if exist the id

Tags: php, mysql

Is my script correct? 
What i want is that check if the id is exist then UPDATE if not exist then INSERT.

```
$sqlCheckRow = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM wctilerack WHERE gameID = '$up_gameID' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
$rowCounted = mysql_num_rows( $sqlCheckRow );
if ( $rowCounted == '0' ) {
    // INSERT wctilerack
    $sqlTileINSERT = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO wctilerack VALUE('', '$up_gameID', '$up_email_player1', '$playerRack' ) ") or die ( mysql_error() );
} elseif ( $rowCounted == '1' ) {
    // INSERT wctilerack
    $sqlTileINSERT = mysql_query( "UPDATE wctilerack SET tiles = '$playerRack' WHERE gamedID = '$up_gameID'  ") or die ( mysql_error() );
}
```

I tested it its working i just like to confirm if the process is correct.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do like this

```
if (empty($rowCounted)) 
{
    $sqlTileINSERT = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO wctilerack VALUE('', '$up_gameID', '$up_email_player1', '$playerRack' ) ") or die ( mysql_error() );
}
else
{
    $sqlTileINSERT = mysql_query( "UPDATE wctilerack SET tiles = '$playerRack' WHERE gamedID = '$up_gameID'  ") or die ( mysql_error() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this

```
INSERT INTO wctilerack VALUES ('', '$up_gameID', '$up_email_player1', '$playerRack')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tiles='$playerRack';
```

Comment: `c=c+1` means "add 1 to `c`, then set `c` to that value". So, in the case of a duplicate key, it adds 1 to `c`.

Comment: Sorry, i was in a hurry before. I have rewritten the query so it fits what you where trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
INSERT into table values (vcolumn1, vcolumn2) on duplicate key update set column1=vcolumn1, column2=volumn2
```